# How to connect Arduino to a switch that doesn't accept 10M?

Tags: arduino-nano, ethernet

I've been playing around with several Arduino ethernet modules based on the ENC28J60 and the W5500 chipset. All modules are advertised as 10/100M, but in reality only work when the port of a switch is configured to handle 10M explicitly.

At this point in time that isn't a problem, however I'll be switching to new switches in the near future that can no longer handle 10M, having 100M as the slowest possible port speed.

How can I still connect my Arduino modules to these new switches (specifically Extreme Networks 5720-48MW)? Are there ethernet modules available that can connect to the 5720-48MW switches? And if so, how do I differentiate these modules, since all modules are advertised as 10/100M?

Comment: Have you actually determined that your new switches will cause problems?

Comment: @StarCat Yes, this is a well known issue, not only limited to these Arduino modules. 10M devices will not work with switches that have speeds of 2.5GBit of higher.

Comment: I see now that the ENC28J60 is regularly advertised as supporting 10/100Mbps speeds but according to its [datasheet](https://nl.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/39662b-62019.pdf) it only supports 10Base-T (10Mbps). The WS5500 should be able to support 10/100 however, if properly implemented.